# mySQL - Make reference to the exception inside the handler

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling, mariadb

Is there a way to make reference to the exception (in the example the `xxx`), caught by the handler, inside the resulting message?

```
declare exit handler for sqlexception select concat('error', xxx);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a specific xxx?

Comment: @RickJames thanks for your reply. Not really, I want to display the error in the `select concat()` in order to have a better idea of where can the problem comes.